# Formatear fecha MySQL (d-m-Y) -> (Y-m-d)

Tags: mysql, date

Estoy intentando formatear la fecha en MySQL pero no lo consigo, el formato de la fecha es el siguiente:

**08-05-2017 - 18:03**

Quiero transformarlo a

**2018-11-09 - 20:30**

Usando

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y - %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d - 
%H:%i') WHERE id = 92
```

Estoy usando bien el STR_TO_DATE y el DATE_FORMAT de la forma correcta?

Gracias

**Edito: Correcto, faltaba el FROM** fallo tonto que no me di cuenta, luego para actualizar usé el UPDATE y listo, muchas gracias a tod@s

```
UPDATE tabla SET fecha = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d - %H:%i') WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Es la forma correcta. ¿Cuál es el problema en sí? Bueno, te falta completar la consulta con el `FROM tuTabla ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu consulta es correcta, claro está, si:

- agregas la parte del `FROM`
- evitas ese espacio en blanco después del guión

Se supone que también agregarás un alias a la columna resultante.

Y, si tu columna fuera del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` no necesitarías `STR_TO_DATE`.  Si es del tipo `VARCHAR` y puedes *normalizar*, entonces hazlo.

La consulta así debería funcionar sin problema:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y - %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d - %H:%i') mifecha 
FROM miTabla
WHERE id = 92
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta está perfecta, excepto que le falta el FROM de la tabla, pero si hacés esta prueba:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('08-05-2017 - 18:03', '%d-%m-%Y - %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d - %H:%i')
```

funciona bien, devuelve

```
2017-05-08 - 18:03
```

Saludos.